# Reverse a dictionary to key : list of values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, mapping, reverse

How to convert a python dictionary `d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:30}` to `{10: [1], 20: [2], 30: [3, 4]}`?

I need to reverse a dictionary the values should become the keys of another dictionary and the values should be key in a list i.e. also in the sorted matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:30}
inv = {}
for key, val in d.iteritems():
    inv[val] = inv.get(val, []) + [key]
```

Try this!

Answer (score 6):

Reversing keys and values in a python dict is a bit tricky. You should have in mind that a python dict must have a `unique` keys.

So, if you know that when reversing keys and values of your current dict will have a unique keys, you can use a simple `dict comprehension` like this example:

```
{v:k  for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

However, you can use `groupby` from `itertools` module like this example:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:30}
b = {k: [j for j, _ in list(v)] for k, v in groupby(a.items(), lambda x: x[1])}
print(b)

>>> {10: [1], 20: [2], 30: [3, 4]}
```

Comment: I don't see how the groupby way would work if the input is not sorted. So for example, if we switch the ordering of a from {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:30} to {1:10, 3:30, 2:20, 4:30}, wouldn't group by fail?

Answer (score 5):

This use case is easily handled by [*dict.setdefault()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30, 4:30}
>>> e = {}
>>> for x, y in d.items():
        e.setdefault(y, []).append(x)

>>> e
{10: [1], 20: [2], 30: [3, 4]}
```

An alternative is to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  This has a slightly more complex set-up, but the inner-loop access is simpler and faster than the *setdefault* approach.  Also, it returns a dict subclass rather than a plain dict:

```
>>> e = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x, y in d.items():
        e[y].append(x)

>>> e
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {30: [3, 4], 10: [1], 20: [2]})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
o = {}
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    if v in o:
        o[v].append(k)
    else:
        o[v] = [k]
```

`o = {10: [1], 20: [2], 30: [3, 4]}`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.