# How to reverse the key value pairs of a dictionary?

Tags: python

Given dictionary is `d1={"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":4}` convert the same to `{1:"a",2:"b",3:"c",4:["d","e"]}`

I have tried and I just got reverse string using key value pair

```
dictionary={"a":1,"b":2,"c":2}
r_dictionary={value:key for key, value in dictionary.items()
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well – the answers in that dupe are still not what OP wants; apparently non-duplicates _shouldn't_ be lists.

Comment: @AKX: tough, that's not a good idea anyway. Better to stick with consistent value types (everything a list or nothing a list, don't mix and match).

Comment: Yep, I'm perfectly aware it's not a good idea. Ah well, not going to reopen this anymore – I guess OP can add `{key: value[0] if len(value) == 1 else value for key, value in d.items()}` to those answers by themselves.

Comment: I also added [Reverse / invert a dictionary mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483666), which has a few more answers on the subject (next to the straight-up-lets-asume-values-are-unique inversions).

Comment: @AKX your solution is wrong you are checking the length of an integer with `len(value) == 1`. It will crash. And in fact, you should not use a short hand because you need to at least use 2 `if statements`. And pls open the question again as no question is answered what if there are duplicate values (there is 1 but it creates every value as a list).

Comment: @HarshitSingh: You are mistaken about no answers to a duplicate question handling duplicate dictionary values.  For example *both* of the answers to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851342/reverse-a-dictionary-to-key-list-of-values) do. So I agree there's no reason to reopen this question.

Comment: @HarshitSingh my addition applies to the duplicates linked.

Comment: @martineau I understand what you are saying but clearly, he also wants a dictionary with no duplicate keys, and also you cannot even create one. See what he wants as output `{1:"a",2:"b",3:"c",4:["d", "e"]}` but every duplicate thing solution is giving him `{1:["a"],2:["b"],3:["c"],4:["d", "e"]}`.

Comment: @HarshitSingh: I think that difference could probably be accounted for fairly easily (although I agree not the way AKX suggested).

Comment: @martineau yeah coz, accessing `{1:["a"],2:["b"],3:["c"],4:["d", "e"]}` would be very easy in comparison to the output he wants, as he would not have to use `if statements` to check if its a list or not

Comment: @AKX I request to open the question because if he  anyways want this output `{1:"a",2:"b",3:"c",4:["d", "e"]}` __only__ . He has the right to know it.

Comment: @HarshitSingh: Making the values always be lists is what Martijn Pieters was saying in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143288/how-to-reverse-the-key-value-pairs-of-a-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment127468999_72143288) early on. If the OP wants it differently then they should be able to figure it themselves from the existing answers (as opposed to getting someone else to do it for them).